# How to handle high traffic for Node-based e-commerce website?

Tags: mysql, node.js, webserver, token, polling

I am trying to design a waiting room system to handle high traffic scenario for e-commerce website. Visitors should query the system until it returns an access token for them to enter the website. I dram a diagram to explain my idea of how the system works as follows:

[image: System works diagram]

But there are some problems which I can make the diagram processing better. I am seeking some suggestions to improve the design above.

Comment: If it's "urgent": **HIRE A QUALIFIED DBA**. Any free advice you get here will only be worth what you paid for it, or in other words, nothing.

Comment: Can you explain what kind of suggestions you are seeking? The token-based entry system is one mechanism for dealing with high traffic (or, more specifically, for avoiding it). The others are a load balancer, web server clusters, regional replication, etc. - but I wonder if your focus is on the token device.

Answer (score 0):

The questions are as follows:-

1. How long do you expect the customers to get the valid token to allow them to proceed accessing the website.
2. Does the token get expire, if yes after how long
3. Is the token pooling the continues process, does the website keeps retry if the customer gets invalid/expired token
4. Does the customer have to know the token or its something that is done on background.